# Azure Service Hub - how to associate a different subscription ID

Tags: web-services, azure-web-app-service

I have set up my first Service Hub service to receive Graph callRecords notifications.

I saw requests coming through successfully but not the messages:

[image: Events Hub Namespace view]

I then realized that the Service Hub instance I'm viewing has the wrong Subscription ID. Along the way I accidentally created a new subscription with my script.

How do I associate the service hub instance to the correct subscription?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I associate the service hub instance to the correct subscription

We can move Azure resources from one Resource Group to another or from one subscription to another.

Navigate to the Portal => Your Resource Group , there you will find an option to Move Resources

[image]

- Select the  Event Hub and click on Move to another Subscription, Select the Target Subscription and Resource Group which you want to move

[image]